# "Greedy" <Delete> and <Backspace> in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

Is there the way to apply "greedy" behavior to  and  keys in Visual Studio? By "greedy" I mean such behavior when all whitespace between cursor position and next word bound can be deleted using one keystroke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can change the binding of the delete key or backspace key - but CTRL+DEL & CTRL+Backspace are pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Ctrl+Shift+Arrow** keys to make the selection and then just hit Delete. You may need to hit the arrow key more than once while still pressing **Ctrl+Shift** combination but because the fingers are in the same position is very fast. This works also for selecting words incrementally.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you will need to do this: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>** - this will give you only the space selected, and then you can press delete.

This is assuming that you are coming from the right, and you have to delete the space to the left.

Of course, this is still 5 keystrokes... but it beats pressing backspace again and again....

Answer (score 2):

Just **Ctrl+Backspace**...

Comment: This will erase all space AND the last word too... I just tested it.

Comment: if your cursor is in the middle of a word ctrl-backspace and then ctrl-delete will get rid of the whole word

Answer (score 2):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Back Space</kbd>** and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>** are also greedy, they delete the nearest word in their respective direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you could write a macro for and then assign to a keyboard shortcut (like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>).

If you explore the EnvDTE namespaces you can do a lot to make changes to text in the active document window. I'd start by checking with something like...

```
    Public Sub RemoveWhiteSpace()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.WordRight(True)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = " "
    End Sub
```

That's just a simple example, but you can extend it further pretty easily

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

Edit.DeleteHorizontalWhiteSpace

I have it set to Ctrl+K, Ctrl+\ which I think is the default, but might not be

Answer (score 1):

As of recent, ReSharper has this as an option. It's on by default, which led to this Q&A: [Visual Studio recent "hungry" or "greedy" backspace behavior update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417166/visual-studio-recent-hungry-or-greedy-backspace-behavior-update)

Perhaps this doesn't qualify as applying the behavior directly in Visual Studio, but it's good to know about.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've got this < Ctrl > thing. And applying this knowledge I've found corresponding VS commands: *Edit.WordDeleteToStart* and *Edit.WordDeleteToEnd*.

I've successfully remapped  < Delete > and < Backspace > keys using Options->Environment->Keyboard dialog. Unfortunately this commands apply not only to whitespace as I'd wish to, but still, thanks everyone!