# Visual Studio recent "hungry" or "greedy" backspace behavior update?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

As of recent, Visual Studio 2017 (and 2019 which I just started using) seems to have changed the behavior of the backspace button, specifically, the cursor is at a place where only white space (lets say tabs) is to the left of the cursor. I used to press backspace and delete one tab. Now, all the white space is removed and my line of code is placed on the end of the line above.

Seems like a good idea and probably is to most people, but the result for me is that I mash the backspace key out of habit and end up backspacing over code from the previous line.

I'd like to ease into this newfangled behavior. Does Visual Studio have a setting to toggle this behavior on and off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, according to this reddit post (where were you yesterday?), it's ReSharper:

https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/by5upb/how_to_disable_greedy_backspace_behavior_in/

Key bit:

> Looks like it was ReSharper all along! Options -> Editor -> Editor Behavior -> Unindent on Backspace. Change from "To proper indent position" to "Disabled"

And sure enough, that was the issue. Good thing I just can't quit you, ReSharper. I suppose this would be yet another selling point, for those that like the greedy-delete or whatever this is called.